# Canvas drawing is slow

Tags: reactjs, performance, canvas

I have a React page that draw about 15K lines on a canvas.
If I draw on a canvas that's not in the document.body, the UI is responsive.
The moment I draw the lines on a canvas that's in the document.body, the UI is very slow.

There's the code:

```
  render() {
    if (this.canvasRef.current && this.state.chartData) {
      const canvas = document.createElement("canvas")
      canvas.width = 1000;
      canvas.height = 800;
      drawChart(canvas, this.state.chartData);
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <canvas ref={this.canvasRef} height={800} width={1000} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Notice if I call the drawChart as

```
drawChart(this.canvasRef.current, this.state.chartData);
```

The UI is extremely slow.

But calling

```
drawChart(canvas, this.state.chartData);
```

The UI is fast.

I also tried copying the drawn canvas to this.canvasRef.current, no help.

Comment: why width= 10000 in the markup if you set it down to 1000 in render? Also we'll need to see what happens in drawChart to be able to help you.

Comment: @Kaiido, my mistake, I changed the question to show that all widths and heights are equal.  Thanks for pointing it out.