# I want to draw in a Worker thread using OffscreenCanvas

Tags: javascript, webpack, web-worker, offscreen-canvas

The process is sent to the webworker according to the conditions in a loop as follows.

```
while () {
　if (~~~) {
  　worker.postMessage({ action: "init", data: offscreenCanvas }, [offscreenCanvas]);
　}
・・・
　if (~~~) {
  　worker.postMessage({ action: "draw", data: offscreenCanvas }, [offscreenCanvas]);
　}
}
```

But once the first message was sent, it didn't seem to be sent after that.

Can I only send it once?

I'm using worker-loader.

Comment: If I didn't send offscreenCanvas, all messages have been received.
Can I only send offscreenCanvas once?

Comment: I kept the first received offscreenCanvas (in worker.ts) and did not send any more, it seemed to work.

I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send offscreencanvas to webworker more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59598111/send-offscreencanvas-to-webworker-more-than-once)